# How can you tell if angles are similar ? How can I prove that the angle $C_1$ equals $A_2$?

Tags: geometry

[image: How can I prove that the angle C1 equals A2]

How can I prove that the angle $C_1$ equals $A_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Extend some lines and use that opposing angles are equal, like this:

[image]

Let me know if this is not enough to get you started, but give it a try first!

Comment: Thanks !! http://prntscr.com/adn3su

Comment: @therue Exactly, great job!